# SWIFT: No idea how to get back the selected value from a popover to the calling controller

Tags: swift, ios8, popover

I just going crazy on Swift Popover “return” values. I am new to Objectiv-C as well as SWIFT but I try to focus on SWIFT.

I checked out tutorials around Google and StackOverflow about how to manage iOS popovers, learned a lot but the last peace I couldn’t make it. It is great so see how easy it is made using Swift and Xcode 6, love it, but I could not figure out how to get back the selected value from my popover to my calling view controller.

So here is my problem:
(SIDENOTE: I am using SWIFT and do all using storyboard)

I have created a master `ViewController` with a button to select currencies. This button opens a “select currency” popover (linked to the `CurrencyTableViewController` (CTV) by CTRL-Dragging it to the CTV-Controller.

So far so good. The thing is, I have no idea how to get back the selected table row (currency) from the CTV-Table ;-( So I need the selected currency (table row) in the calling `ViewController`.

This is an excerpt from my `ViewController` (which is calling the popover)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate 
[...]
// This button is calling the popover
@IBAction func buttonCurrency(sender: AnyObject) {
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? CurrencyTableViewController {
controller.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
return
}
}
[...]
```

Hopefully somebody can help me with that missing last mile how to get back the selected row value back to my ViewController.

Thanks in advance

Cheers

John

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made quick example, hope it helps:

```
// This is you popover's class

@objc protocol CurrencySelectedDelegate {
    func currencySelected(currName: String)
}

class MyPopOverController: UIViewController {


    weak var delegate: CurrencySelectedDelegate?


    @IBAction func readyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Do what you want

    delegate?.currencySelected("Euro/Dollar etc....")

    // close popover
    }
}

// ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController, CurrencySelectedDelegate {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" { // your identifier here
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! MyPopOverController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

And remember just declare that currencySelected function in your ViewController.

Comment: Thanks Prontto! that helped and I could manage to implement it.

I just had one compile error `let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! MyPopOverController`and I had to remove the exclamation marl after the `as`